# Repeating current loop iteration if some condition is met (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I'm writing a bash script which takes files and directories as arguments.

It will loop through its arguments and rename the current argument if some condition is met. When this happens I want also to repeat the current loop iteration.

Can I do such thing without resorting to while or c-style for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `while` instead of `if` when checking the "some condition".

```
for file in "$@" ; do
    while [[ $file ... ]] ; do
        mv "$file" ...
    done
done
```

Comment: Without while or c-style seems bit odd.

Comment: @Keys: Bash doesn't have a [redo](http://p3rl.org/redo)...

Answer (score 0):

```
for FILE in <Your_Path>
do
if [ -f $args ]; then
    if [ <check_your_condition_here> ]; then
    mv $args $args_renamed
    fi
elif [ -d $args ]; then
    if [ <check_your_condition_here> ]; then
    mv $args $args_renamed
    fi
fi
done
```

Simply set the flags to repeat the loop for that iteration, which needs to be dynamic considering the runtime values.
IHTH